# Как закрыть модальное окно при клике вне него?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть у меня модальное окно (всё в конце), которое нормально открывается / закрывается при вызове функции. Но надо, чтобы окно закрывалось при клике вне окна (затемненный фон), а если я на него накидываю функцию закрытия окна, то при клике по окну оно закрывается (я так понял из-за того, что окно является дочерним элементом). как это реализовать?

```html
<div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="in-header">
                <i class="fa fa-close" onclick="closeModal()"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="in-body">
                Суперкрутой текст, вообще что угодно
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```js
function closeModal() {

    $('.modal-body').stop().animate({
        marginTop: '-100%',
    }, 300, function(){
        $('.modal').animate({ opacity : 0 }, 200, function(){
            $('.modal').css({ 'display':'none' });
            $('.modal-body').css({ 'marginTop':'100%' });
            $('body').css("overflow", "auto");
        });
    });

}

function showModal() {

    $('.modal').css("display", "flex");
    $('body').css("overflow", "hidden");

    $('.modal').animate({
        opacity: '100%',
    }, 150, function() {
        $('.modal-body').animate({
            marginTop: 0
        }, 200);
    });

}
```

PS изначально задано opacity: 0, а для modal-body: margin-top: 100%, сначала показывается фон, потом снизу выплывает окно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поставьте отлов события клика на фон, а там проверяйте, попадает ли клик в модальное окно, и если нет, то закрывайте его:

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('.modal')) {
        closeModal();
    }
});
```

Другие примеры подобного решения можете найти в [аналогичном вопросе на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37573608/5308802) и на [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/vlrprbttst/pen/xOoxWo).